What does the Canada's Access to Information Act entail for reference letters?
I am writing a reference letter for someone applying to a university in Canada. The site (ubc.ca) where I submit the reference letter states:

It is the policy of the University to treat reference information as confidential. It can, however, be required under Freedom of Information legislation to disclose the substance of any reference but only where it can be done without disclosing the identity of the writer.

I am unfamiliar with Canada's Access to Information Act (ATIA). What does "where it can be done without disclosing the identity of the writer" mean? Does that mean anything that can allow at least one person to guess the the identity of the writer? (in which case, >90% of the letter can't be disclosed)

What are you actually worried about? Did you want 100% of the content to be available under ATIA? One reference might state "This person has been known to me since 1980 and I consider them to be wholly trustworthy and of good character", which doesn't reveal anything about the writer, and another might say "When this person worked for me on my XYZ project for ABC in 1980 they showed competent and thorough working practices", which might. What is unclear about "only where it can be done without disclosing the identity of the writer"?

@WeatherVane "What are you actually worried about? Did you want 100% of the content to be available under ATIA? " I just want to understand. "which doesn't reveal anything about the writer" unless you're the person being referred, or possibly other close persons.

As Jen explained, that particular federal statute (Access to Information Act) only applies to the federal government.
Most access to information and privacy (ATIP) rights are provided at the provincial level.
In british-columbia, the main relevant legislation is the Freedom of Information and Protection of Privacy Act. Every university in British Columbia is a public body subject to the Act (Schedule 1, "educational body").
Notably, the law provides exemption to disclosure when it "would be an unreasonable invasion of a third party's personal privacy" [s. 22(1)]. The disclosure is presumed to be unreasonably invasive when

22(3)(h) the disclosure would reveal
(i) the identity of a third party who supplied, in confidence, a personal recommendation or evaluation, character reference or personnel evaluation, or
(ii) the content of a personal recommendation or evaluation, character reference or personnel evaluation supplied, in confidence, by a third party, if the applicant could reasonably be expected to know the identity of the third party

Normally, when refusing disclosure of information supplied in confidence under the "unreasonable invasion" section, the public body must nonetheless disclose a summary of the information. However, an exemption further applies:

22(5) On refusing, under this section, to disclose personal information supplied in confidence about an applicant, the head of the public body must give the applicant a summary of the information unless
(a) the summary cannot be prepared without disclosing the identity of a third party who supplied the personal information, or
(b) with respect to subsection (3) (h), either paragraph (a) of this subsection applies or the applicant could reasonably be expected to know the identity of the third party who supplied the personal recommendation or evaluation, character reference or personnel evaluation.

If there is only one reference chosen by the applicant, 22(5)(b) would certainly apply. If there are two, it is very likely that the exemption applies. But if there are three, four, etc.? The exemption may still apply, but it would depend on the circumstances to judge whether the applicant could reasonably be expected to know the identity of the supplier of reference. For example, a summary containing the average of numerical scores supplied by several references would probably be treated differently than a summary that would contain evaluations regarding a specific role the applicant held.
In Langara College (Re), 2016 BCIPC 1 (CanLII),  the Commissioner found that s. 22(5) does not prevent the disclosure of peer grades (without disclosing the identities of peer graders) received by a student in a class of 36 students.

Note that provincial laws differ. In Alberta and Quebec for example, letters of reference supplied for admission purposes usually have to be disclosed by public bodies.
And if you are an employee of a public institution and provide letters of recommendation as part of your official duties or employment, additional access to information legislation may apply on your own side.

Given that the question asks about a particular federal statute, by its specific short title, I will confine my answer to that statute's applicability. Therefore this is not legal advice or even legal information that would be helpful to understanding the meaning of the quote which motivated this question. You cannot rely on this answer — or any answer — about the Access to Information Act to help you understand the information in the quote.
The Access to Information Act, R.S.C. 1985, c. A-1 is only relevant for access to records under the control of "a government institution" (s. 4(1)). "Government institution" in that statute means (s. 2):

(a) any department or ministry of state of the Government of Canada, or any body or office, listed in Schedule I, and
(b) any parent Crown corporation, and any wholly-owned subsidiary of such a corporation, within the meaning of section 83 of the Financial Administration Act;

These are all federal institutions, and would have to be. Universities are not subject to Canada's Access to Information Act.

Thanks, I thought under Freedom of Information legislation = under Canada's Access to Information Act (ATIA). Is that incorrect? I know nothing.
